# Flutter error Method "contains" can't be unconditionally

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I havea bug where my code cant be build because this errorr
can someone look my code
here the code

```
Text(
                    "Login", 
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                    new TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (input) => !input.contains("@")
                        ? "Email id Should be Valid"
                        : null,
                    
                    )
              ],
              ),
              ),
            ),
```

> it show error message "The method 'contains' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' try making the call conditional (using '?.' or adding a null check to target

can someone please fix my bug
thanks before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use:

```dart
TextFormField(
   keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
   validator: (input) => !(input?.contains("@") ?? false)
      ? "Email id Should be Valid"
      : null,
)
```

As per the official documentation [FormFieldValidator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldValidator.html), the validator parameter is an optional String. So you need to convert that to non-nullable String first.

Comment: its shows "the return type 'bool' isnt a string?, as required by the closure's context

Comment: @HandikaPramudyaPutra: Please check the updated answer, you've to only replace that line, don't change the remaining code.